# unable inject grails app context in src/groovy

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have created custom event listener that extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener as described in the Grails docs http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html and it works fine, however. i am unable to inject Service in this listener if doing as follows.

```
    def context = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
def myService = context.myService
```

The 'context' returns null.

Any ideas what may be the problem. Thank You
p.s. GRails 2.1.2

Comment: The context returns null or the context is null?

Comment: Sorry for my English. The context is null or ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT) returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in applicationContext to your Listener as a constructor argument when you register it.

Comment: Thank you Todd. i was confused for little bit...in so much Magic:) Instead of argument, i keep the constructor as is and assign service after initiation before registering event.

Comment: def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->       application.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { k, datastore ->
            def cacheListener = new CacheListener(datastore)
            cacheListener.nodeDriverProxyService = applicationContext.nodeDriverProxyService
            applicationContext.addApplicationListener cacheListener